# Showing that there is a finite chain of sets connecting any two distinct points in a connected metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I self study and have no where else to ask this, please do not give me an answer/corrected proof but I wouldn't mind hints. I appreciate any help

**Question:** Let $\mathrm X$ be a connected metric space. Let $\mathit x, y$ $\in$ $\mathrm X$ be distinct points. Let $\varepsilon$  > $\mathrm 0$.  Show that there is a chain of open sets $\{ U_1, U_2, ... U_n\}$ such that diam $U_i$ < $\varepsilon$ for each $\mathit i$ with $\mathit x$ $\in$ $U_1$ and $\mathit y$ $\in$ $U_n$. A chain of sets is a collection $\{A_1, A_2, ... A_n\}$ such that $A_i$ $\cap$ $A_j$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$ if and only if $\mathbf |$$\mathit i - j$$\mathbf |$ $\leq$ $\mathrm 1$.

**Proof:** Let $\mathrm A$ be the set of all points of $\mathrm X$ such that for each $\mathit a$ $\in$ $\mathrm A$ there is a chain of open sets $\{ U_1, U_2, ... U_n\}$ where diam $U_i$ < $\varepsilon$ for each $\mathit i$ with $\mathit x$ $\in$ $U_1$ and $\mathit a$ $\in$ $U_n$. We will show that $\mathrm A$ is open in $\mathrm X$ and that it must contain every point of $\mathrm X$, otherwise we would have a separation.

Given $\mathit a$ $\in$ $\mathrm A$, there is a chain of open sets $\{ U_1, U_2, ... U_n\}$ connecting $\mathit x$ to $\mathit a$. Now consider the open ball $\mathrm B(a, \delta_a)$ where $\mathit \delta_a$ is chosen such that diam $\mathrm B(a, \delta_a)$ < $\varepsilon$, and for each $\mathit b$ $\in$ $\mathrm B(a, \delta_a)$ consider $\mathrm B(b, \delta_a)$. If $\mathrm B(b, \delta_a)$ $\cap$ $U_1$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$, then $\{U_1, \mathrm B(b, \delta_a)\}$ is the desired chain of sets connecting $\mathit x$ to $\mathit b$, otherwise we check if $\mathrm B(b, \delta_a)$ $\cap$ $U_2$ is empty. This reasoning proceeds for each $\mathit i$, and if $\mathrm B(b, \delta_a)\,$$\cap$ $U_i$ $\mathrm =$ $\emptyset$ for $\mathrm 1 \leq \mathit i \leq \mathrm n-1$ then $\{ U_1, U_2, ... U_n, \mathrm B(b, \delta_a)\}$ is the desired chain of sets connecting $\mathit x$ to $\mathit b$, due to the fact that $\mathit a \in \mathrm B(b, \delta_a)\,$$\cap$ $U_n$ $\neq \emptyset$. This proves that $\mathit b \in \mathrm A$, so $\mathrm B(a, \delta_a) \subset \mathrm A$ and $\mathrm A$ is open in $\mathrm X$.

Now suppose that $\mathrm A$ doesn't contain every point of $\mathrm X$. For each $\mathit p \in \mathrm X - A$, choose $\delta_p$ so that diam $\mathrm B(p, \delta_p)$ < $\varepsilon$. There are two cases, either $\mathrm B(p, \delta_p) \cap \mathrm A = \emptyset$ or $\mathrm B(p, \delta_p) \cap \mathrm A \neq \emptyset$, we will show that a contradiction arises in both cases.

If $\mathrm B(p, \delta_p) \cap \mathrm A \neq \emptyset$ then we can use the same reasoning as above to show that $\mathit p \in \mathrm A$, contradicting the fact that $\mathit p \in \mathrm X - A$

If $\mathrm B(p, \delta_p) \cap \mathrm A = \emptyset$ then the union $\cup \,\mathrm B(p, \delta_p)$ of all these balls is open and disjoint from $\mathrm A$, forming a separation of X, thus $\mathrm A$ must contain every point of $\mathrm X$

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct and nice. You can do it a bit faster. To show that the set $A$ is open it sufficies to observe that all points from $U_n$ belong to $A$ (which chain?) and it's a nbhood od $a$.

The second part is a bit worse, since you fix $p$ and analysing one case you take all such $p$'s. It's better to prove that the set $X\setminus A$ is also open and you can do it just like you did in the second part.